# Can't find a proper signature for a function using STUArray (neither can GHC)

Tags: arrays, haskell, state, monads, state-monad

I built a function for finding the determinant of a matrix using the ST-Monad and unboxed STArrays (STUArray). The type for a matrix is the following:

```
newtype Matrix e = Matrix (Array Int (UArray Int e))
```

that is, an immutable array containing immutable unboxed arrays containing the elements. This will require me to add the Predicate `IArray UArray e` to functions dealing with `Matrix`, which in turn requires `FlexibleContexts`. Okay, done.

The function used to calculate the determinant has the following signature:

```
detST :: (IArray UArray e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s),
          Num e, Eq e, Division e)
   => Array Int (UArray Int e) -> ST s e
```

I am required to also add the Predicate `MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)` since internally the arrays are converted into mutable arrays (the outer boxed, the inner unboxed).

This function can be used like so:

```
main = do
    let m@(Matrix x) = matrix [ [1,-2,3,234]
                              , [5,2,3,-3]
                              , [7,18,3,40]
                              , [2,9,71,0] ]
        d = runST (detST x) :: Int -- needed for type check, ambiguous otherwise

print d
```

Works, fine. But look how ugly it is! Of course I do not want to give away the internals of of `Matrix` (at least not further than the predicates attached to my functions already make me to). I would like to define the following function:

```
det :: Matrix e -> e
```

And I can't.

I tried without a proper signature:

```
det (Matrix arr) = runST (detST arr)
```

fails. Fair enough, I'll put my brain to work: `detST` requires `IArray UArray e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s), Num e, Eq e, Division e`, so does `det`, doesn't it?

```
det :: (IArray UArray e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s),
          Num e, Eq e, Division e) => Matrix e -> e
```

fails. But I don't see how. The message that GHC (**7.4.2**) gives me is:

```
Could not deduce (MArray (STUArray s) t (ST s))
  arising from a use of `detST'
```

but that exact term is in the predicates!

GHC suggests:

```
add (MArray (STUArray s) t (ST s)) to the context of
  a type expected by the context: ST s t
  or the inferred type of
     det :: (Eq t, Num t, IArray UArray t, Division t) => Matrix t -> t
or add an instance declaration for (MArray (STUArray s) t (ST s))
```

Okay. As to my understanding I have done that first thing. Also there does exist an instance for that `(MArray ...)` (otherwise, how could I have used it successfully in main?!).

I am not sure about what is wrong here. I believe it has something to do with the "hidden" ST state in `s`, and that the s of `detST` is some other `s` than the `s` in `det` would be, but I don't know how to write a type for this.

**What is the proper definition of `det` - and why?!**

The program without `det` compiles fine by using only `FlexibleContexts`, no warnings with `-Wall`. The complete source code can be found **[as a gist here](https://gist.github.com/scravy/5317395)**.

Comment: To begin with - why not just use an UArray indexed with (Int, Int) instead of an array of arrays?

Comment: So that I can easily switch the rows. Anyways, there are of course other possible versions of this program. But I want to know why I can't define that particular function and what is wrong with it.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `detST` so that we can test your code? I don't quite understand why it needs to be in `ST`.

Comment: The complete code is linked as a gist, see the last four words of the question. It needs to be in ST since it works with an STUArray internally. i.e. detST is the function which should be the internal function, and det the one I would publicly export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this to work using the trick described by Keegan McAllister [in this article](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.se/2010/09/higher-rank-type-constraints.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, GADTs #-}

data Evidence s e where
  Evidence :: (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => Evidence s e

data ElemType e = ElemType (forall s. Evidence s e)

det :: forall e . (IArray UArray e, Num e, Eq e, Division e)
       => ElemType e -> Matrix e -> e
det (ElemType e) mat = runST (f e mat)
  where
    f :: Evidence s e -> Matrix e -> ST s e
    f Evidence (Matrix arr) = detST arr
```

Usage:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let m = matrix [ [1,-2,3,234]
                   , [5,2,3,-3]
                   , [7,18,3,40]
                   , [2,9,71,0] ]
    print $ det (ElemType Evidence) (m :: Matrix Int)
```

The problem stems from the lack of higher-rank constraints - `runST` has type `(forall s. ST s a) -> a`, so you need a constraint like `forall s . MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)`, which are not supported by GHC. This trick allows you to convince the type checker that the constraint actually holds. A more in-depth discussion of this problem is available in the article I linked above.